# Launch MAUI application from another application with response

Tags: c#, .net, maui-windows

I am trying to launch MAUI app-A from MAUI app-B in Windows.
After launching app-A, I want that app-A will send in response some API-Object to control app-A from app-B.

I need to control more than one instance of App-A from App-B, so that each instance of app-A need to return its own API-Object.

1. I tried to use `Microsoft.Maui.ApplicationModelLuncher`
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/appmodel/launcher?tabs=windows
   but it doesn't return value as response (it returns true/false for success/failure)
2. I tried to use `Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriForResultsAsync`

```
 var testAppUri = new Uri($"App_A:"); // The protocol handled by the launched app
 var options = new LauncherOptions();
 options.TargetApplicationPackageFamilyName = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.Id.FamilyName;

 var inputData = new ValueSet();
 inputData["sn"] = sn;
 LaunchUriResult result = 
          await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriForResultsAsync(testAppUri, options, inputData);
```

but I am getting exception

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Element not found.

Comment: If you are comfortable with a Windows-only solution, then you can use a variety of IPCs to communicate between the processes: named pipes, sockets, zeroMQ or other broker, COM, even stdin/stdout redirection. There is no need to use the MAUI-specific API if you do not need a cross-platform solution (although it is a good idea to use the cross-platform API if it exists and meets the task requirements).

Comment: thanks, I used  named pipes eventually. :)

Comment: Did you solve this @YChabany ? How do you launch app-A from app-B?